# source of System.nanoTime overhead?

Tags: java

Running  benchmark on my computer `Linux Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4430 CPU @ 3.00GHz`. I have a granularity of 36ns and a latency of 37ns for the method `System.nanoTime().`

I am concerned about where this 36ns is spent, Is it the time for the Operating System to access the registers and get the value of the current time ?

Comment: Why are you concerned about 36 ns? That's 0.000000036 seconds.

Comment: I don't this is a duplicate as I want to know how it works internally, I have already tried debugging with gdb but got no result

Comment: You think 108 processor instruction are too much? I don't think there is a time register (as a CPU register), so it's a bit more that accessing EAX or something

Comment: I have only found this post about the native implementation de nanotime http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/what-is-behind-systemnanotime.html

Comment: On bigger applications this overhead will be accumulated.